# php output function return through classes

Tags: php

this is my code, semplified
I'm trying to output something, returned form other functions, but it doesn't work.
I've tried also using `self::` instead of `$this->`

```
class a{
    function a(){

        return "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah";

    }
    function b(){
        return "bbbbbbb";
    }
}
$a = new a;
class b{
    function ea($a){
        return "oajs$a";

    }
    function f(){
        global $a;
        $blah = $this->ea("asd");
        $blah .= $a->a;
        return $blah;
    }
}
$b = new b;
echo $b->f;
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `$b->f` is looking up a **property** of class `b`. You have a **method** `f()` therefore you want to `echo $b->f()`. Since you're using classes, you don't need to mess with `global`, you can simply inject an instance of `a` and use that. Injection can be done via constructor or a setter method on class `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```
class a {
    public function a(){
        return 1;
    }
    public function b(){
        return 2;
    }
}
class b{
    public $a;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = new a();
    }
    public function ea($a){
        return "ao$a";
    }
    public function f(){
        $blah = $this->ea("stuff");
        $blah .= $this->a->b();
        return $blah;
    }
}
$b = new b();
echo $b->f();
```